# How do I get incoming request IP address in Java Play 1.2.4

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I see in Play! 2.0 there is Http.Context.current()
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/java/play/mvc/Http.Context.html#current()

But in Play! 1.2.4 how would I go about getting the current HTTP request's IP Address?

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are within the controller, you can do

```
request.remoteAddress;
```

Otherwise, you would need to do

```
Http.Request.current.get().remoteAddress;
```

Comment: This is correct but if you are using Apache as a front end server you want to look at request.headers.get("x-forwarded-for")